# how can i extract certain words with space and puctuation in R

Tags: r, regex

I have this document, and I want to extract certain words using R

```
 a = "people/NN + is/VB
no/AJ + one/NC + can/VA
certain/AJ + man/NN + is/VB
```

(each string set is escaped by enter)

I want to extract these words (the words collocated with verd "is")

```
"people" "man"
```

so I tried this code but didn't work

```
b = "([A-Za-z]+)/[N]\\s+\\sis/VB"
str_match_all(a, b)
```

Please let me know the regular expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
a = c("people/NN + is/VB", 
      "no/AJ + one/NC + can/VA", 
      "certain/AJ + man/NN + is/VB", 
      "every/AJ + one/NC + is/VB")

library(stringr)
word_N <- str_match(a, "([a-zA-Z]+)/[N][a-zA-Z]*\\s*\\+\\s*is/VB")[,2]

word_N[!is.na(word_N)]

#[1] "people" "man"    "one"
```

Comment: thank you but variable "a" is not vertorized like "c("a","b", "c")".

Answer (score 0):

I think the below regex will do the trick for you.

```
r <- "[a-zA-Z]+(?=\\/NN\\s\\+\\s(is))"
```

I have done the matching with the base package's pattern matching and it worked for the above given example. Do test it further.

```
m <- gregexpr(r,a,perl = TRUE)
regmatches(a,m)[[1]]
```